# Firebase authorized domains not allowing my Svelte project?

Tags: firebase, svelte

I am using Svelte + Firebase for a web app. However, When I try to authorize my Svelte project URL (it is an unchanged URL, default IP address), the firebase console just doesn't let me. On another computer, I never had this issue, and when I import all the same settings from that device to my home one, nothing changes, still can't seem to get it to work.

To be completely honest, I have no idea what could be any kind of relevant code or screenshots, so if you need anything just tell me what to look for and I will include it in the question.

EDIT: here is the screenshot of my authorized domains:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your authorized domains? By default, Firebase adds `localhost` to the list of authorized domains. Is your svelte project running on localhost?

Comment: @RafaelZasas I only have the default domains authorized, I will include an image in just a moment.  Also, no, I am using the svelte hosting with the IP address, as I found it simpler in the past to use svelte hosting and then implement Firebase.

Comment: Is it a static IP (unchanged between sessions)? If that is the case you may just want to paste that IP in the authorized domains.

Comment: It is static, however the firebase console is telling me that it is an invalid domain.

Comment: Please add the IP of your local svelte server. Also, you don’t need to preface your edits with “Edit”

Comment: I just found the answer and I am kind of dumb... my IP is http://127.0.0.1:5173. I played around with it after you mentioned whether or not it was static and if I remove everything after the ":" then it authorizes it...I am so sorry for wasting your time man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248004/discussion-between-rafael-zasas-and-dwkk).

Answer (score 0):

So Basically just remove the port, thank you Rafael Zasas for helping me figure it out.

the default URL looks something like this:
http://198.05.032.0:5000

the port is everything after the ":". Removing it, as well as the colon itself, makes it a valid domain in the authorized domains section in the Firebase Console.

Comment: I appreciate the acknowledgment, but please add a description of the steps you took so solve the issue (removing the port) and then mark this as the correct solution. This helps future readers to find the solution quickly.